# What do do if Mathematica stops without error messages?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages, parallelization, error-tracking

I am trying to run the relatively simple code

```
(*Limits Mathematica to requested resources*)
Unprotect[$ProcessorCount];$ProcessorCount = 14;

(*Setting up the assumptions to be used in the whole calculation*)
$Assumptions = {_ \[Element] Reals, x > 0, y > 0}

(*Setting up the function to integrate*)
g1[x_, y_] :=
 2 Exp[-(x + y)] (2 Log[4 x y] + 2 (x + y) - 7 - (1/x + 1/y) +
4 EulerGamma + Exp[2 Min[x, y]]/Min[x, y] -
2 ExpIntegralEi[2 Min[x, y]])

Integrate[ g1[x/a,y/b] * (x/(a^4)) * (y/(b^4)) * Exp[-0.5((x/a)+(y/b))] , {a,0,1}, {b,0,1}   ]
```

I say relatively simple as I understand this is a hard integral to do, but I can do this on a relatively average desktop in my office (Mathematica 12 on Ubuntu 20.04).

However, if I try to do this either on my personal computer (Windows 10, Mathematica 12), then after a few minutes, the Mathematica notebook just "quits" . I assumed it's probably due to low memory (which is weird as my laptop actually has more memory than the desktop, but why not), so I tried running the same code on a supercomputer I have access to. However, on the supercomputer, the code stops too. The output is:

```
Mathematica 12.0.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2019 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=
In[2]:=
In[3]:=
In[4]:=
In[5]:=
Out[5]= {_ ∈ Reals, x > 0, y > 0}

In[6]:= In[6]:=
In[7]:=
In[8]:= In[8]:=
```

So it seems like I get the exact stopping-without-any-errors behavior on a supercomputer.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I kindly ask Mathematica to provide at least an error message to me?

EDIT: I should clarify that the unprotecting of of the processor counts is only done on the HPC code and not on my desktop or laptop.

Comment: Happens for me too on 12.3.1 even though I have 48GB of RAM on this machine. The process memory usage increases for a few minutes then it crashes the kernel. The notebook didn't quit though.

Comment: I don't know if quit is the proper word, that's why I put it in parentheses. It acts like if I were to run the command Quit[]. The windows remains open.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @LaBelleCroissant  Returns an answer with version 12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021), on my PC.